# cifs mount fails with "mount error(112): Host is down"

Tags: samba, fstab, shared-folders, cifs, smb

I'm trying to mount a USB drive plugged on my Technicolor router.

I have the following line in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
//192.168.1.1/usbdisk /media/public cifs guest,vers=3.0 0 0
```

After trying resolving the issue with diffrerent instructions found from the net I have tried specifying different versions, vers=2.0, vers=2.1, but none of these have resolved the issue.

If I test with smbclient, I get the following:

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.1/usbdisk /media/public -o username=myuser,vers=2.0
Password for myuser@//192.168.1.1/usbdisk:  *********
mount error(112): Host is down
```

Same happens with no user specified, and also with various `vers=` definitions.

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10.
Any ideas?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. It was working for months and now went down. No updates on either side.

Comment: Hi, since I updated from Ubuntu fromn 17.04 to 17.10 I have the same issue. Smbclient still works, also trhough gvfs I can access the share

Answer (score 9):

You can disable the entry in `/etc/fstab` and issue the following command

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/usbdisk /media/public -o guest,vers=3.0
```

and at the same time play around with different options (behind -o). If you need feedback from you system, you might open a second terminal windows and type `journalctl -fb` to watch how the kernel reacts on your options given.

I explain all this because your real issue might be different with cifs than it was in my case.

I had the problem that the device offering SMB wants `ver=1.0`. While Ubuntu 17.04 didn't have any problems with the version (auto), the 17.10 and its kernel demands to indicate the number, as my Kernel logs shows:

```
Okt 25 09:06:08 gespc kernel: No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB3 (vers=3.0), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 specify vers=1.0 on mount. For somewhat newer servers such as Windows 7 try vers=2.1.
```

My Good luck!

Comment: My problem was the version, I needed to set vers=1.0. `journalctl -fb` helped to understand that.

Comment: In my case the problem was only version number. Following command worked for me: `sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/usbdisk /mnt -o username=testuser,vers=1.0`. I am directly mounting to system provided `/mnt`

Comment: This would be brilliant, except for the fact that on my system, `journalctl -fb` didn't actually provide any useful feedback.

Answer (score 5):

YES !

Had this problems for months too, solved with adding vers=1.0 in the options:

`//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/disk /media/foldername cifs rw,credentials=/etc/samba/credentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770,iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0 0 0`

Thanks Gerhard!

GR

Comment: Same was applicable in my case.